# Add class when element is at top of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create sticky headers that when you scroll to a div the head state becomes fixed and stays in view, when the div has come to an end and scrolls out of view I want the title to then become absolute and stay at the bottom of its parent.

I've got the initial part working only I'm struggling on adding the 'absolute' class...

https://jsfiddle.net/yw313vf2/1/

```
function fixTitle() {
  $('.service-pane').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var offset = $this.offset().top;
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > offset) {
      $this.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      $this.removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
}

$(window).scroll(fixTitle);
```

Comment: $this.addClass('fixed absolute'); ?

Comment: I need to add the absolute class when the parent div has scrolled out of view @Roy

Comment: Add the absolute class to what element?

Comment: To the parent  $('.service-pane') @Roy.

Comment: $this.parent().addClass('absolute');

Comment: $this.parent().addClass('absolute'); work?

Comment: No, I'm trying to create something similar to this @Roy http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/1/

Comment: I cant understand you, sorry, please, explain what is the problem, and dont tell me "I need to add the absolute class when the parent div has scrolled out of view"  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138333/discussion-between-liam-and-roy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to run another check within the function to see if when scrolled the end of my div had reached the top of the window and if so add an additional class...

```
function fixTitle() {
  $('.service-pane').each(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     var offset = $this.offset().top - 50;
     var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scrollTop > offset) {
      $this.addClass('fixed');
      if ($this[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom < $('.manifesto').height() + 50) {
          $this.addClass('absolute');
      } else {
          $this.removeClass('absolute');
      }
  } else {
    $this.removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
}
```